# Problemas con java + logback-ecs-encoder

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, logger

Tengo un proyecto de Spring-Boot que funciona sin problema y quiero adicionarle el ecs-encoder de Elastic   para generar logs listos para ElasctiSearch, la configuración del proyecto es la siguiente:

dependencia añadida en el pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-ecs-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

archivo logback-spring-xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
        <include resource="co/elastic/logging/logback/boot/ecs-file-appender.xml" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
        <logger name="project.zuul.service.log" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ECS_JSON_FILE"/>
        </logger>
    </configuration>
```

La clase donde estoy haciendo el logging:

```
    @Log4j2
    public class ProjectLogger {

        private ProjectLogger() {
        }

        public static void logProjectInfo(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            log.trace(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
        }

    }
```

Se supone que debería obtener un archivo log.json con la información en formato json, pero sigo obteniendo sólo el log normal, qué puede ser el problema?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que para que el log sea visible, se debe configurar el nombre del archivo de log en el archivo application.properties asi:

```
    # for Spring Boot 2.2.x+
    logging.file.name=/path/to/my-application.log
    # for older Spring Boot versions
    logging.file=/path/to/my-application.log
```

así se generará el log normal con el nombre **my-application.log** y el log ecs con el nombre **my-application.log-json**