# ¿Comó configurar correctamente log4j2 en Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

Estoy intentando configurar los logs en mi proyecto Spring, pero a la hora de llamar a los métodos que usan el logger, se me crea los ficheros que tengo configurados, pero vacíos.

La configuración de mi xml es la siguiente:

src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="3600">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">./logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Appender Console -->
        <Console name="searchFilesConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <!-- Appender Exceptions -->
        <RollingFile name="searchFilesAppenderEXCEPTION"
            fileName="${log-path}/searchFiles_exception.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/searchFiles_exception_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1} - %M] Line %L - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                    onMismatch="DENY" />
            </Filters>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- Apennder Info -->
        <RollingFile name="searchFilesAppenderINFO"
            fileName="${log-path}/searchFiles_info.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/searchFiles_info_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1} - %M] Line %L - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                    onMismatch="DENY" />
            </Filters>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- Appender DEBUG -->
        <RollingFile name="searchFilesAppenderDEBUG"
            fileName="${log-path}/searchFiles_debug.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/searchFiles_debug_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1} - %M] Line %L - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                    onMismatch="DENY" />
            </Filters>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.victorproyects" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="searchFilesAppenderDEBUG" level="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="searchFilesAppenderEXCEPTION" level="error" />
        <appender-ref ref="searchFilesConsoleAppender" level="ALL" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="searchFilesConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Mi pom tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.victorproyects.utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>searchFiles</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>searchFiles</name>
    <description>Jar to search fo files in a directory with a pattern</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Y llamo al logger de la siguiente forma:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RunnerSearchFile {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Prueba de logger");
    }

}
```

Pero se me pintan vacíos los ficheros, no me escribe nada.

Comment: cuál es le nombre de tu archivo xml y en que lugar de tu proyecto se encuentra?

Comment: Es ```log4j2.xml``` y está en ```src/main/resources```.

Comment: ya intentaste cambiarle el nombre a logback-spring-xml? por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374702/problemas-con-java-logback-ecs-encoder

Comment: No estoy usando esa dependencia, estoy usando la siguiente: ```spring-boot-starter-log4j2```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun lo que puedo analizar, el error debería solucionarse verificando estos 2 puntos:

**Punto 1:**
Si
ejecutas el `main` de la clase `RunnerSearchFile` no iniciara el contexto de spring lo cual puede causar que no escriba en el log o si estas iniciando la aplicación con la respectiva clase anotada `@SpringBootApplication` el contexto de spring iniciara pero no ejecutara el `main` en el componente `RunnerSearchFile` sino el constructor, la forma correcta seria:

```
package com.victorproyects;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RunnerSearchFile {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public RunnerSearchFile() {
        log.info("Prueba de logger");
    }
}
```

**Punto 2:**
Verifica que el paquete es correcto para tu aplicativo `<Logger name="com.victorproyects" level="debug" additivity="false">` la propiedad name debe coincidir con el paquete base de tu proyecto.

Comment: Efectivamente, poniéndolo como dices en el paso 1 me funcionó.